# How to implement sentence similarity in Orange Data Mining Tool?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, orange, sentence-similarity

I am trying to implement Sentence Similarity in NLP domain and wanted to know how to effectively utilise the Orange Data mining tool.

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be nice if you provided a minimal example with some data and what you are trying to achieve.

I assume you have a text and you wish to inspect how similar sentences in this text are. First, you will have to split your text into sentences and put them in separate rows (one sentence per row). There's a script for that in [orange-scripts](https://github.com/biolab/orange-scripts/pulls). Then use any of the clustering approaches, bag of words or document embedding. You can find tutorials on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmNPvQr9Tf-bxmjlFRg0AGjMzzd1y8_kB).